# 【MTAはSendgrid】$_SESSIONでファイル間のデータが引き継がれない。

Tags: php, html

Sendgridのサンプルを使って送信環境を作っています。

https://sendgrid.kke.co.jp/blog/?p=1066

以下のように、３つのファイルがあり、index.htmlからconfirm.phpへのデータの受け渡しはうまく行き、画面にはHTMLで表示されています。

index.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
 省略
</head>
<body>
 〜
<div class="field">
 <label>お名前</label>
 <input id="fullname" type="text" name="fullname" placeholder="例：山田 太郎">
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

confirm.html

```
<? php
if(!$_POST) {
header('Location: ./index.html');
session_start();
$_SESSION["fullname"] = $_POST["fullname"];
};
?>
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
 省略
</head>
<body>
 〜
 <form id="form" action="sendmail.php" method="post">
    <p>お名前：<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_POST["fullname"]); ?></p>
    <button type="submit">
    <img src="images/submit.png" class="submit-btn">
    </button>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

ところが、

sendmail.php

```
<?php
 session_start();
 if(!$_SESSION=["fullname"]) {
 header('Location: ./index.html');
 };

 var_dump($_SESSION);

 require 'vendor/autoload.php';
 $dotenv = new Dotenv\Dotenv(__DIR__);
 $dotenv->load();

 $api_key           = $_ENV['API_KEY']; <--独自の環境変数から読み込み
 $from              = $_ENV['FROM']; <--独自の環境変数から読み込み
 $tos               = explode(',', $_ENV['TOS']); <--独自の環境変数から読み込み

 $fullname = $_SESSION["fullname"]; <-- 20行目

 省略

 $sendgrid = new SendGrid($api_key, array("turn_off_ssl_verification" => true));
 $email = new SendGrid\Email();
 $email->setSmtpapiTos($tos)->
   setFrom($from)->
   setFromName("送信者名")->
   setSubject("[申し込みが来ました] %fullname%さんから申し込みが来ました")->
   setText("%fullname%さん \r\n ")->
   setSubstitution('%fullname%', '$fullname')-> <--43行目

 省略
 ?>
```

と書きました。そしたら、

array(1) { [0]=> string(8) "fullname" } 
Notice: Undefined index: fullname in /var/www/html/lp/sendmail.php on line 20

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method SendGrid\Email::setSubstitution() in /var/www/html/lp/sendmail.php:43 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in /var/www/html/lp/sendmail.php on line 43

Notice: Unknown: Skipping numeric key 0 in Unknown on line 0**

とエラーを吐きました。画面上はデータが表示されていましたが内部的にデータを保持できておらず、fullnameに上書きされてしましました。これをデータをきちんと渡せれば解決するとおもうので、どうしたらデータを引き継げるのか教えてください。

Comment: マルチポスト　https://teratail.com/questions/80479

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if(!$_SESSION=["fullname"]) {
  header('Location: ./index.html');
};
```

値の比較は `==` や `===` で行います。`=` は常に代入を行います。

で、そこを直して `!$_SESSION == ["fullname"]` とすると、セッション変数が `["fullname"]` という配列に等しいかという比較になるのですが、そういうことをしたいのではないですよね？

もし、連想配列 `$_SESSION` に `"fullname"` というキーが存在するか（そのキーで値が保存されているか）を調べたいのでしたら、`isset()` や `array_key_exists()` といった関数を使います。例えば次のようになります。

```
// $_SESSION["fullname"] が設定されていなければリダイレクトする
if(!isset($_SESSION["fullname"])) {
  header('Location: ./index.html');
};
```